# drawRect control flow for storyboard and customUI

Tags: ios, swift

My custom UI for storyboard times out often, so I was hoping to make separate UIs for storyboard and the device. My question is, how to know that the `drawRect` is executed from `storyboard` by `Xcode`.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

   let isStoryboard = ... //< How to know this is called for `storyboard` ?
   if (isStoryboard) {
      drawForStoryboard()
   } else {
      drawForCustomUI()
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a piece codes from github. It seems like `#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` can distinguish who execute `drawRect`.

```
override public func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        drawIBPlaceholder()
        #else
        drawChart()
    #endif
}
```